# Adobe Acrobat XI cannot be deleted or installed again

Tags: windows-10, adobe-acrobat

I installed Adobe Acrobat XI about a year ago. I wanted to uninstall it and install the new version but during the uninstall suddenly the computer shuts down and now I cannot uninstall or install another version. When I want to uninstall it it gives this message.

[image]

When I personally want to find the .msi I can't. What should I do?

I am using Windows 10 Home 64-bit.

Comment: Did you try putting a Reader distribution into the according location so that the specified `.msi` is now present? It should be exactly the same version that you had installed, but with any luck, a similar one might do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The uninstall failed. What should I do?

There are several programs that will clean up leftovers that remain after a failed uninstall.

Try one (or more) of the following options and then try to install again the new version of Acrobat.

---

#### Option 1 - Download and run the [Adobe Reader and Acrobat Cleaner Tool](http://labs.adobe.com/downloads/acrobatcleaner.html)

> The Adobe Reader and Acrobat Cleaner Tool is designed to fix such issues by **cleaning up corrupted installations, including removing or fixing corrupted files, removing or changing permissions registry entries, etc**.
>
> The tool provides options for removing problematic Acrobat items only while leaving Reader untouched and vice versa.

Notes:

- Because of US Economic Sanctions there may be restrictions on downloading US software from Iran (where the OP is located).
- If you can't download the program directly from Adobe (because you are in Iran and it is blocked) you can use the following link [AcroCleaner for 10.x and later](http://gof.ir/11p9z/acrobat_ittools_cleaner_p2_061713.zip.html) (accessible from Iran).

---

#### Option 2 - Download and run [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) by [Piriform](https://www.piriform.com/)

The registry clean option may fix any issues that prevent you from running the installer for the newer version of Acrobat.

> System Requirements
>
> Windows 10, 8.1, 8, 7, Vista and XP. Including both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   versions.

...

> We also offer a portable version for installing on USB thumb drives.
>   Visit the builds page to download.

It includes a [Registry Cleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/registry-cleaner):

> The Registry Cleaner will remove entries for non-existent applications, and it'll also fix invalid or corrupted entries.

The free version of [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download) has this capability.

[image]

When you choose to fix any registry issues you are given the option to backup the registry changes.

---

#### Option 3 - [Microsoft Troubleshooter](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed)

> Follow these steps to automatically repair issues including corrupted
>   registry keys that block you from installing or removing programs:
>
> 1. Click the [Download](http://aka.ms/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) button on this page.
> 2. In the File Download dialog box, click Run or Open, and then follow the steps in in the Program Install and Uninstall
>      Troubleshooter.
>
> Notes:
>
> - This troubleshooter might be in English only. However, the automatic fix also works for versions of Windows in other languages.
> - If you’re not on the computer that has the problem, save the troubleshooter to a flash drive or a CD, and then run it on the
>     computer that has the problem.
>
> [Download](http://aka.ms/Program_Install_and_Uninstall)
>
> **What it fixes**
>
> - Corrupted registry keys on 64-bit operating systems
> - Corrupted registry keys that control the update data
> - Problems that prevent new programs from being installed
> - Problems that prevent existing programs from being completely uninstalled or updated
> - Problems that block you from uninstalling a program through Add or Remove Programs (or Programs and Features) in Control Panel

Source [Fix problems that block programs from being installed or removed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed)

---

#### Option 4 - Download and run [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)

> IObit Uninstaller 3 is a light and FREE uninstall tool that helps you
>   to remove unwanted programs and leftovers completely without any
>   hassle. It detects and categorizes all of the installed programs, and
>   allows bulk uninstallation with just ONE click!

Source [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html)

---

#### Option 5 - Download and run [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html)

> Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" control panel applet.
>
> Revo Uninstaller is a much faster and more powerful alternative to "Windows Programs and Features (Add or Remove Programs)" applet! It has very powerful features to uninstall and remove programs.

There is a freeware version available.

Source [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html)

---

#### Disclaimer

I am not affiliated with [Piriform](https://www.piriform.com/), [IObit Uninstaller 3](http://www.iobit.com/advanceduninstaller.html) or [Revo Uninstaller Pro](http://www.revouninstaller.com/index.html) in any way, I am just an end user of the software.

Comment: Excuse me my access is declined for every version isn't there any other download links?

Comment: @TahaAkbari Not that I know of. The links work for me.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: Did you check-mark the agreement clause?

Comment: @harrymc Yes I did when I click on the download link it shows me  that your access is declined.

Comment: @TahaAkbari: Try another browser, and please let us know the exact error you are getting and which browsers you tried.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Or try using a proxy to download the file if it's not your browser's issue.

Comment: @TahaAkbari I've mirrored the correct download on my personal Google Drive, you can use this if you want: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4X-46PyqacSZFlCdUxSdjZHSXc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @TahaAkbari Answer expanded to include some other option to resolve your issue.

Comment: @MarkYisri Nice idea, but if Adobe finds out ... by offering the file you have bypassed the agreement clause ...

Comment: @TahaAkbari lives in Iran, that's why he can't access links on Adobe. I'm sending you a mirror

Comment: @AmirHossein Then how did he get a new version of Acrobat?

Comment: @DavidPostill Hello Uncle David :) There are redistribution sites here like Soft98.ir that allow people to download contents under sanction.

Comment: @AmirHossein Thanks. Will add that link to the answer.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Link to downloadable version of the software (Adobe Reader and Acrobat Cleaner Tool) from an Iranian website added to the answer.

Comment: @David you might want to prove that this link isn't junk... several websites like that block my browser from accessing.

Answer (score 0):

Locate the Adobe Acrobat folder, and delete it. I know it doesn't sound professional, but whenever a program would not install, I just deleted everything it could use, (start menu items, desktop icons, etc, etc) and restarted. Try to install the newer version after that. Good luck!

Comment: @Taha I recommend you try this solution. Has worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

First, it may be nice to know where Windows is getting the
`C:\Users\sobhan\Desktop\Adobe Acrobat XI\Adobe Acrobat XI\AcroPro.msi`
from.  I suspect you'll be able to see that command if you go to a command prompt and run this:

`reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall /s | find /i "UninstallString" | find /i "Adobe Acrobat XI"<BR>`

It doesn't seem like you need to have a UAC-elevated command prompt.  (However, some programs do give different results based on if UAC is enabled.  Most give an error message, like "`net session`", but others just give a different result.)

You can chop off everything after the pipes if you want to see more info, like the DisplayName value.

Note: If you choose to use the graphical interface, RegEdit, then you should know that HKLM is a shortcut for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

I'm noticing the `Adobe Acrobat XI\Adobe Acrobat XI\AcroPro.msi` filename you mention is under your Desktop.  My guess is that these files got deleted, likely in an attempt to clean up a desktop.  You could try to somehow restore the file to that location, but that probably won't be super easy and so it won't be worth the effort.  In all honesty, you're probably more likely to be better off just using a method to manually clean off the software (deleting the files), and then eliminate the related entry from HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
Just deleting the files (for the old version) may not seem like a very thorough cleaning job, as that approach may leave behind some registry entries.  However, chances are that nearly every one of those remaining registry entries are likely to just be used once you get the new version installed, so you can rest easy knowing that you're not leaving a ton of useless clutter in the registry.

Now, as for why you can't install, I don't know.  I don't think people should be expected to know, based on the very limited information you've provided so far.  There are probably tons of different reasons that an installation program could break.  I remember working for a computer support company and a business just couldn't get their Adobe installed.  Turns out that an employee had run some software that cracked the old version of Adobe, and that software modified the HOSTS file (in C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc) which had a bunch of lines related to Adobe.  (And we had a very good idea of just what employee did such a thing.)  I cleared out those entries from the HOSTS file, and may have done some more work (like flushing the DNS cache, with IPConfig/FlushDNS), and then I was easily able to register the new version (like what the business was trying to properly do).  So that's a real-world experience that did happen.

However, I do suspect your cause may be entirely different.  Because there are numerous reasons why a software installation could fail, finding out why Adobe won't install is probably really worth a separate question by itself, and more details on what you experience when you try to install it.